# Compile time generated constant type ID

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing an event system as a part of a hobby project, a 2D game engine. As part of the event system design, I need to map objects in base of what templated derived class they represent. To better illustrate the problem, consider the following simplified code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
    int getTypeId() {return typeId_;}
    static bool compareIfSameType(Base *a, Base *b)
        {return a->getTypeId() == b->getTypeId();}
protected:
    int typeId_;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int typeId) {typeId_ = typeId;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> obj1(1);
    Derived<float> obj2(2);
    Derived<float> obj3(2);

    if(Base::compareIfSameType(&obj1, &obj2))
         cout << "obj1 and obj2 are of equal type\n";
    else cout << "obj1 and obj2 are not of equal type\n";
    if(Base::compareIfSameType(&obj2, &obj3))
         cout << "obj2 and obj3 are of equal type\n";
    else cout << "obj2 and obj3 are not of equal type\n";
}
/*output:
obj1 and obj2 are not of equal type
obj2 and obj3 are of equal type*/
```

There is no actual problem with this code, but the requirement of manually passing a number identifying the type of each derived class instance is very cumbersome and quite error prone.
What I want is to automatically generate the typeId from the type of T at compile time:

```
Derived<int> obj1;
Derived<float> obj2;
Derived<float> obj3;

if(Base::compareIfSameType(&obj1, &obj2))
    //do something...
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused what exactly do you need to achieve at compile time

Comment: currently I am passing an integer to the constructor of each derived class object denoting the type of the derived class. I would like to have that ID generated automatically.

Comment: Ok you confused me a little because there is a built in thing called `typeid` you shouldn't give things the same names as built ins

Comment: Have you considered `std::is_same`? - possibly in combination with decltype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the question of the wisdom of a design that requires comparing type for equality, you can do that with `typeid`. No need to write your own. `Base* a` and `Base* b` point to objects that have the same derived type if `typeid(*a) == typeid(*b)`.

Comment: That would work but that's  runtime type identification, and a compile time generated constant would suffice.

Comment: Sure it is. All of the `typeid` information is generated by the compiler when it compiles the program. If you mean something else by "compile-time generated" you need to explain exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: Is there a performance penalty to using typeid() instead of hardcoded magic numbers? I do realize this is premature optimization, just asking.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, of course, but typically nothing noticeable. Each type has a corresponding `typeid` object, and each object of any polymorphic type has a vtable  for the virtual function pointers; the vtable will also usually have a pointer to the appropriate `typeid` object. So comparing `typeid`s just requires getting each object's `typeid` pointer and comaring the pointers. That's one more indirection for each object than you'd get for an ordinary data member.